# How do I go about fixing my Nokia Lumia 1020 (Windows Phone 8.1)?

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020

My Lumia 1020 was at 6% battery life when i decided to charge it, only to realize that it was not charging. I proceeded to check the power outlet by plugging in another electronic device which worked; I assumed then that the charger must be the problem. I tested the charger with an older phone and it worked. I tried a different charger on the Lumia 1020, but it did not work either.

I then concluded that perhaps something was wrong with the mini usb port, so I took it to a technician who told me that power was reaching the board inside and he thinks it is a software error. This not charging issue has happened once or twice before, but usually disconnecting the charger and reconnecting it had resolved it in the past.

I took the phone home, by which time the battery seemed to have hit zero and the phone would not turn on. It didn't even show the battery image nor the Nokia logo when power was pressed. I tried a soft reset and a hard reset to no avail. Though, I am not sure if those would work with the battery completely dead. I then plugged it into the wall socket for 24 hours and the windows logo did not even blink once. I left it to charge in my computer for 15 hours, but again it didn't work. Also tried Nokia recovery tool for windows phone 8.1 devices but as the battery is completely dead my computer cannot detect the device so that is a dead end. I should probably note here that when i first noticed the device was not charging in the wall outlet I plugged it into my computer and got an error messaging along the lines of "usb device malfunction. power surge blah blah blah." After which all my usb connected devices including mouse and keyboard stopped working, and I was force to restart my computer and disconnect the phone to get everything back to normal.

At this point I am not sure what else to do. I really like this phone, but I don't intend to buy a new one. Any suggestions on how to get it back to normal would be helpful.

Comment: There is some kind-of short in your mobile's mini-usb port, try reaching to auth' service center.